# Neo4j node persistence issue on a simple use case

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm currently implementing some test sample to learn neo4j and spring data thank the cineast project and other sample like spring-data hello-worlds...

Unfortunately I'm facing now a problem I don't understand even if I already spent some times on the eclipse debugger on my code and the other sample codes to try to compage and so find a solution. This problem is particularly blocking for me as I can't validate the Neo4j persistance even if it should really be a trivial use case...

Here is the class I'm testing :

```
@NodeEntity 
public class SimplePersonImpl {
@GraphId 
private Long nodeId;

@Indexed
private String    id        = null;

@Indexed(indexType=IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "LastName")
private String    lastName  = null;
@Indexed(indexType=IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "FirstName")
private String    firstName = null;

public SimplePersonImpl() {

}

public SimplePersonImpl(String firstName_, String lastName_) {
    this.firstName=firstName_;
    this.lastName=lastName_;
    this.id=this.firstName+"."+this.lastName;
}

public String getID() {
    return this.id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setID(String id_) {
    this.id=id_;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName_) {
    this.firstName=firstName_;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName_) {
    this.lastName=lastName_;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    SimplePersonImpl person = (SimplePersonImpl) o;
    if (nodeId == null) return super.equals(o);
    return nodeId.equals(person.nodeId);

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return nodeId != null ? nodeId.hashCode() : super.hashCode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Person{first name='%s', last name='%s'}", firstName, lastName);
}
}
```

I'm currently testing this class thank the following jUnit test cases :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"/yes-test-context.xml"})
@Transactional
public class SimplePersonImplTest {
@Autowired Neo4jTemplate template;

@Rollback(false)
@BeforeTransaction
public void cleanUpGraph() {
    Neo4jHelper.cleanDb(template);
}

@Test @Transactional
public void persistedPersonShouldBeRetrievableFromGraphDB() {
    SimplePersonImpl qqun          = template.save(new SimplePersonImpl());
    SimplePersonImpl retrievedQqun = template.findOne(qqun.getNodeId(), SimplePersonImpl.class);
    assertEquals("retrieved person matches persisted one", qqun, retrievedQqun);
}

@Test @Transactional
public void persistedPersonWithPropertiesShouldBeRetrievableFromGraphDB() {
    SimplePersonImpl qqun = template.save(new SimplePersonImpl("testFN","testLN"));

    SimplePersonImpl retrievedQqun = template.findOne(qqun.getNodeId(), SimplePersonImpl.class);
    assertEquals("check memory first name matches persisted one", qqun.getFirstName(), retrievedQqun.getFirstName());       
    assertEquals("check memory last name matches persisted one", qqun.getLastName(), retrievedQqun.getLastName());
}
}
```

The first test is running successfully but the second one fails. When checking with eclipse debugger I can see that :

- after the save methode return a SimplePersonImpl qqun with correct firtName, lastName and id values. But the nodeId is null and I don't understand why. But as this behavior is the same on the spring-data hello-worlds sample I guess my problem is not coming from there.
- in the findOne method even if nodeId is null in my qqun object the qqun.getNodeId() return 1. I don't understand from where is coming this value but let's continue
- the findOne method return a retrievedQqun. All the retrievedQqun properties are null and it seems to be the reason why my first assertEquals on the firstName fails.

Here I really don't understand where I did something wrong (I guess I did) but it's clear there is many things behind spring-data neo4j persistance I don't understand. I'll would be happy to get some answers on these points (why I see nodeId=null after a save call ? why I retrieve a non null object with all properties to null ? ... ) .

The last point where there could be some errors is my test context configuration but again I don't see where the problem could be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:component-scan base-package="yes.ds.domain.neo4j"/>

<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.test.ImpermanentGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown"/>
<!-- <neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/neo4j-db"/> -->
<neo4j:repositories base-package="yes.ds.repository.neo4j"/>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"/></beans>
```

Thank you

Comment: I think your confusion comes from the interception that aspectj does, it intercepts the field access from within your class and looks into the node properties for those values instead,

the fields in the class are not taken into account for this.

Does none of the getters return a value?

As an experiment: can you try to instead of setting the fields in the constructor directly to either set them externally or with the setters?

Comment: I already tested with setter before the save call : same behavior...

Comment: I've found the issue to my problem. I'm not sure if it directly relates to your issue, but if you create a custom Relationship class (for [at]RelatedToVia Relationships), and relationships created using that class will automatically have a __type__ property with the name of the package and class of the Class. If you have an [at]Query that creates the relationship as well, that query will not also create the __type__ property. This causes issues when the relationships are loaded later, thus causing the missing __type__ property issue. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think i encountered a similar issue in a Test-Entity I created.
In that particular case I forgot to annotate a getter-method with `@Transactional`.

The annotation `@Transactional` is required both on getters and setters of `NodeEntities`, otherwise they behave like you described. Adding the annotation fixed it for me.

Transaction support has to be enabled of cause.